# How to detect the completion of a Google Form in a Webview

Tags: android, ios, webview, google-forms

I am loading a Google Form in a webview and need to know when the user has completed the form.
The form may have one, or multiple sections (pages).

**What I tried**

Parsing the URL for an information unique to the form submission event:
The url ends with `https://.../viewform` on the first page of the form
The url ends with `https://.../formResponse` on the form submit thank you page, but also starting the second page and every page after that (and when going back a page).
So this method only works for single-page forms.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified version

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            webView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('freebirdFormviewerViewResponseConfirmContentContainer').length > 0") {
                val done = it == "true"
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Form "Thank you" page has a unique div `.freebirdFormviewerViewResponseConfirmContentContainer`.
By injecting javascript in the webview when the page is loaded, we can detect the presence of this div and call a method from our JavascriptInterface to notify the native code that the form was submitted:

Note: this only works if the Google Form is loaded directly in the webview. This doesn't work if the Google form is embedded in a website via an iframe (I found it impossible to detect that submission event in that case).

(Java code as example)

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                String js =
                    "( " +
                    "function() { " +
                    "if(document.getElementsByClassName('freebirdFormviewerViewResponseConfirmContentContainer').length > 0) {" +
                    WEBVIEW_INTERFACE_NAME + ".googleFormSubmitted();" +
                    "}" +
                    "}) " +
                    "()";

            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                mWebView.evaluateJavascript(js, null);
            else
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
            }
        }
    );

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(getContext()), WEBVIEW_INTERFACE_NAME);
    }
}

private class WebViewInterface
{
        Context mContext;

        WebViewInterface(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void googleFormSubmitted()
        {
            // Do what you need
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This just changed overnight. The answer from @Julian Honma is still the right one, but from what I can see, the class name is now `vHW8K`, at least in the forms I am using.